# Im trying to submit a form with ajax but im getting NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument

Tags: php, ajax

This is the page with the form that is being submitted. I starred the code that has the   form

```
<html>

<head> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/homepage.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'> 


</head>

<body>

<img src="wc.png" id="wc">

<div id="banner"> <h1> Wolfeboro Connection </h1> </div>

<div id="feed"> <iframe src="feed.html" id="iframefeed"> </iframe> </div>

<div id="footer"> </div>


<div id="accounts">   <table> <tr> <th> Sign In </th> </tr>
<tr> <td> Username </td> <td>  <input type="text" name="loginusername"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Password </td> <td> <input type="password" id="loginpassword"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td> <td> <input type="submit" value="submit"> </td> </tr>


</table>

**<table>
<tr> <th>Sign Up </th> </tr>  
<tr> <td>Restaurant Name </td> <td>  <input type="text" id="signupusername"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Password </td> <td> <input type="password" id="verifypassword"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Verify Password </td> <td> <input type="password" id="signuppassword"> 
</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> Phone Number </td> <td> <input type="text" id="phoneNumber"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Email </td> <td>  <input type="text" id="email"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td> <td> <input type="button" value="submit" id="signupsubmit"> </td> </tr>
</table>**

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is the ajax that im trying to submit the form with

```
$(function () {


$("#signupsubmit").click(function() {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "signup.php",
data: { name: signupusername, password: signuppassword , phonenumber: phoneNumber ,    
email: email }
});

});

});
```

This is the page with the php

```
 <?php


    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'brewster01', 'WolfeboroConnection');



    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();

    if($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO users 
    (BusinessName, Password, Phone, Email) VALUES (?,?, ?, ?)")) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    }
    else
    {
    error_log(mysqli_error($db));
    }


?> 

[04:16:51.977] NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
```

Comment: Where do you set the variables `signupusername`, `signuppassword`, etc.?

Comment: Where did you get these variables?
`data: { name: signupusername, password: signuppassword , phonenumber: phoneNumber ,    
email: email }
`

Comment: they are strings from whatever is submitted from form on my html page

Comment: you should use $_POST["nameofvariable"] variable when using post data.

Comment: Your query is also incomplete, but maybe you didn't copy-paste the entire thing.

Comment: i am posting with ajax so i dont need $_POST right?

Comment: the query is complete i am using php msql prepared statements

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Scroll far to the right to see the rest of the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Input elements are not automatically translated into variables, you have to get their values using a method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "signup.php",
    data: { name: $("#signupusername").val(), 
            password: $("#signuppassword").val(),
            phonenumber: $("#phoneNumber").val(),    
            email: $("#email").val()
    }
});
```

In the PHP, after you prepare the statement, you need to do:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['phonenumber'], $_POST['email']);
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? You don't have a callback function, so it doesn't report the success or failure of the AJAX call.

Comment: Your PHP doesn't bind the `$_POST` parameters to the prepared statement parameters.

Comment: sorry im very new trying to teach myself with some help so im not sure what you mean do i need to submit it to the error console some how?

Comment: The server script should echo something to report success or failure. `$.ajax` should have a `success:` option that provides a function to call when the AJAX call completes. Its argument is whatever the script echoes. It can display an alert, put the result in a DIV, or whatever you want. See the documentation for examples.